# How to publish a tag only if not blank

Tags: git, jenkins

I'm experimenting with getting a Git project working in Jenkins.

I found an interesting blog post here: [Building a Continuous Delivery Pipeline with Git & Jenkins](https://stackify.com/continuous-delivery-git-jenkins/)

Ms. Padget is using a parameterized Jenkins job with two parameters:

- ${COMMIT_HASH} - what to checkout and build
- ${TAG} - A tag to push.

The commit to checkout defaults to /refs/heads/master. The tag to apply has no default.

There is a post-build Git publisher action, that pushes the specified tag if the build is successful.

The problem is that the ${TAG} parameter is not mandatory, and if it's left blank the attempt to PUSH the empty value generates errors.

There is an option, on the Git Published action, to push only if the build succeeds. What I'd like is that it push only if the build succeeds *and* if ${TAG} is specified.

Is there someway to make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't actually solve the issue, but it is a reasonable work-around.

If you set a default for the ${TAG} parameter, and set the "Force Push" option on the Git Publisher task, it will overwrite the tag on every build.

We're setting the default to "most_recent", and that seems to be working.